# Extracting values of a pandas DataFrame using maximal indexes from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'a': [1, 2, 3],
 'b': [2, 4, 2],
 'c': [3, 1, 5],
 'd': [-1, 0, 1]
}, index=('A', 'B', 'C'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
 'a': [0, 5, 10],
 'b': [9, 5, 1],
 'c': [3, 4, 2],
 'd': [12, 3, 0]
}, index=('A', 'B', 'C'))

>>> print(df1)
   a  b  c  d
A  1  2  3 -1
B  2  4  1  0
C  3  2  5  1
>>> print(df2)
    a  b  c   d
A   0  9  3  12
B   5  5  4   3
C  10  1  2   0
```

I would like to get the value from each column of `df1` that corresponds to (i.e. is at the same coordinates as) the maximal value of that same column in `df2`. So in the above example it should return the values `[3, 2, 1, -1]`. I was able to get the correct indices using `idxmax`:

```
>>> print(df2.idxmax())
a    C
b    A
c    B
d    A
dtype: object
```

As you can see, these are indeed the indices corresponding to the column-wise maximums in `df2`. However trying to index into `df1` using these indices does not return the desired result:

```
>>> print(df1.loc[df2.idxmax()])
   a  b  c  d
C  3  2  5  1
A  1  2  3 -1
B  2  4  1  0
A  1  2  3 -1
```

This indexing seems to only use the values of the `Series` returned by `idxmax`. How do I correctly index `df1` using both parts (labels and values) of the returned `Series`? Or is there maybe a simpler solution to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
s = df2.idxmax()
[df1.loc[row, col] for col, row in s.items()]
```

Comment: That will do it. I solved the issue using `np.diag`˙, since I realized the desired results made up the returned `DataFrame`'s diagonal, but this seems much cleaner and more intuitive.

Comment: I used `df1.at` here instead of `df1.loc`, not sure if there would be much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vectorial solution (not a loop), you can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

a = df1.to_numpy()[np.argmax(df2.to_numpy(), axis=0),
                   np.arange(df1.shape[1])]
# array([ 3,  2,  1, -1])

# as Series
out = pd.Series(a, index=df1.columns)
```

output:

```
a    3
b    2
c    1
d   -1
dtype: int64
```

If you have only 1 max value per column, you can use this pandas alternative:

```
out = df1.where(df2.eq(df2.max())).T.stack()
```

output:

```
a  C    3.0
b  A    2.0
c  B    1.0
d  A   -1.0
dtype: float64
```

*NB. if you want you can `droplevel(-1)` for the same output as the first approach.*